# How can I write the data to csv column by column from for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

I have several for loops and each loop output many lines of code I need to combine all of them column by column, I'll attach the code below in order to explain and show my request:

```
myFile = open('example2.csv', 'w')

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0 div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.d-flex.justify-content-center.flex-md-row.align-middle.align-items-center.justify-content-md-start.p-0.m-0 div.mr-md-3.mx-2.mb-md-0.text-3xl.font-semibold')
for linka in links:
    linka = str(linka.text)
    print(linka+'\n')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
for linkb in links:
    linkb = str(linkb.text)
    print(linkb+'\n')

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(3)')
for linkc in links:
    linkc = str(linkc.text)
    print(linkc+'\n')

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0.mb-2.d-flex.flex-column-reverse.flex-sm-row div.col-md-9.col-lg-7.p-0 div.d-flex.flex-column.mx-3.mx-sm-5.mx-md-0 div.coin-link-row.mb-md-0')
for linkd in links:
    linkd = str(linkd.text)
    print(linkd+'\n')
myData = [["Linka", "Linkb", "Linkc","Linkd"],
          [linka,linkb,linkc,linkd]]
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)
```

plus I usually got that error

```
I/O operation on closed file
```

I need the out put in the CSV file be like below

```
Linka, Linkb, Linkc, Linkd
linka(loop no 1), linkb(loop no 1), linkc(loop no 1), linkd(loop no 1)
linka(loop no 2), linkb(loop no 2), linkc(loop no 2), linkd(loop no 2)
linka(loop no 3), linkb(loop no 3), linkc(loop no 3), linkd(loop no 3)
linka(loop no 4), linkb(loop no 4), linkc(loop no 4), linkd(loop no 4)
```

Update the below code:

```
 for one in many:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(str(one.text) + '\n')
                one.click()
                with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                    writer.writerow(["Linka", "Linkb", "Linkc", "Linkd"])
                    linksa = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                        'html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0 div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.d-flex.justify-content-center.flex-md-row.align-middle.align-items-center.justify-content-md-start.p-0.m-0 div.mr-md-3.mx-2.mb-md-0.text-3xl.font-semibold')
                    linksb = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
                    linksc = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(3)')
                    linksd = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                        'html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0.mb-2.d-flex.flex-column-reverse.flex-sm-row div.col-md-9.col-lg-7.p-0 div.d-flex.flex-column.mx-3.mx-sm-5.mx-md-0 div.coin-link-row.mb-md-0')

                    for linka, linkb, linkc, linkd in zip(linksa, linksb, linksc, linksd):
                        writer.writerow([linka.text, linkb.text, linkc.text, linkd.text])
```

Thank you Barmar you solved my problem (Kindly guys vote up for @Barmar answer because I don't have enough reputation for that, actually he deserve)

Comment: Where does `myFile` come from? Looks like it's already closed.

Comment: It would be great if you could simplify this post [into a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It should be `with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myFile:`

Comment: @brunns I added this point, I already added it in my code but I didn't copied it to here.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're overwriting `linkb`, `linkc`, etc. each time through the loops.

Comment: @Barmar I already use it mate

Comment: If you used it correctly you wouldn't get that I/O error.

Comment: Where does `linka` come from? You only create `linkb`, `linkc`, and `linkd` in the posted code.

Comment: @Barmar I added it you can check now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `with open` not just `with`.  [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

To use `write_rows`, you provide an iterable with your rows already prepared. You could do this by preparing each list of linka's, linkb's, etc. and then putting them together, if you could assume they are always the same amount of each.

```
linkbs = []
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
for linkb in links:
    linkb = str(linkb.text)
    linkbs.append(linkb)

# then put myData together
myData = [[linkas[i], linkbs[i], linkcs[i], linkds[i]] for i in range(0, len(linkas)]
# as Barmar suggested you could instead use zip()
# zip(linkas, linkbs, linkcs, linkds)
with open('example.csv', 'w') as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)
```

You need to build each list, I only did one here as an example, and this method only works if every list will be the same length, otherwise you would need to account of making them the same length first or catching indexError later.

Comment: I think his main question is about generating the correct CSV file contents, not how to open the file.

Comment: @Barmar, exactly I want to know how can I output the data column by column by using the different data came out from the mentioned loop

Comment: Gotcha, I'll fix then.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I tried your code and got the same error ```I/O operation on closed file
``` and nothing appeared in the csv file

Comment: Can you post all of your fixed code when it comes to the CSV writer and the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to process all the links in a single loop. You can do this using `zip()` to combine all the lists.

```
linksa = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0 div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.d-flex.justify-content-center.flex-md-row.align-middle.align-items-center.justify-content-md-start.p-0.m-0 div.mr-md-3.mx-2.mb-md-0.text-3xl.font-semibold')
linksb = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
linksc = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(3)')
linksd = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0.mb-2.d-flex.flex-column-reverse.flex-sm-row div.col-md-9.col-lg-7.p-0 div.d-flex.flex-column.mx-3.mx-sm-5.mx-md-0 div.coin-link-row.mb-md-0')

with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerow(["Linka", "Linkb", "Linkc","Linkd"])
    for linka, linkb, linkc, linkd in zip(linksa, linksb, linksc, linksd)
        writer.writerow([linka, linkb, linkc, linkd])
```

For your bigger loop, you should first write the header line outside the loop. Then open the file in append mode each time through the loop.

```
with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerow(["Linka", "Linkb", "Linkc","Linkd"])

for one in many:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(str(one.text) + '\n')
    one.click()

    linksa = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0 div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.d-flex.justify-content-center.flex-md-row.align-middle.align-items-center.justify-content-md-start.p-0.m-0 div.mr-md-3.mx-2.mb-md-0.text-3xl.font-semibold')
    linksb = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
    linksc = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(3)')
    linksd = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0.mb-2.d-flex.flex-column-reverse.flex-sm-row div.col-md-9.col-lg-7.p-0 div.d-flex.flex-column.mx-3.mx-sm-5.mx-md-0 div.coin-link-row.mb-md-0')

    with open('example2.csv', 'a') as myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        for linka, linkb, linkc, linkd in zip(linksa, linksb, linksc, linksd)
            writer.writerow([linka, linkb, linkc, linkd])
```

Comment: I used it @Barmar but the issue each time the loop run the new output overwritten the old output came from the previous loop

Comment: What previous loop? This is used to create the entire file from scratch.

Comment: If you want to add to a file without removing the old contents, use `a` instead of `w` when opening the file. But then you'll get multiple header lines.

Comment: I think you were seeing me, that what happened I got multiple header, and only got the last results from the last loop which I stopped the system on it.

Comment: You can open the file once, write a single header, then write multiple loops that write rows to it.

Comment: I added this at the begging of the code before the links variable ` with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myFile:
                writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                writer.writerow(["Linka", "Linkb", "Linkc", "Linkd"]) 
`
and added this in the same you did 
` with open('example2.csv', 'a') as myFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                    for linka, linkb, linkc, linkd in zip(linksa, linksb, linksc, linksd):
                        writer.writerow([linka.text, linkb.text, linkc.text, linkd.text])
`
but I only got the header in the csv

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it all at once.

Comment: If I want to work with 4k ouput I have to repeat the code 4k time??

Comment: Of course not. Each `for` loop creates many rows. You only need as many different loops as you have different selectors to process.

Comment: I stuck, the code is so sensitive therefore I couldn't upload it all here

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I assumed that each `driver.find_XXX()` is selecting many elements in the document that match the selector or XPath.

Comment: I made it like below I added some of the rest code I use for loop in order to click on button after I click on that button I went to a new page which I apply the links variable on it and the code will be like below:

Comment: ` for one in many:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(str(one.text) + '\n')
                one.click()
                with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                    writer.writerow(["Linka", "Linkb", "Linkc", "Linkd"])

Comment: linksa = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                        'html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0 div.col-lg-8.col-md-8.d-flex.justify-content-center.flex-md-row.align-middle.align-items-center.justify-content-md-start.p-0.m-0 div.mr-md-3.mx-2.mb-md-0.text-3xl.font-semibold')
                    linksb = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
                    linksc = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(3)')

Comment: linksd = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                        'html body div#wrapper div.container.coins div.mt-3 div.col-12.row.p-0.m-0.mb-2.d-flex.flex-column-reverse.flex-sm-row div.col-md-9.col-lg-7.p-0 div.d-flex.flex-column.mx-3.mx-sm-5.mx-md-0 div.coin-link-row.mb-md-0')

                    for linka, linkb, linkc, linkd in zip(linksa, linksb, linksc, linksd):
                        writer.writerow([linka.text, linkb.text, linkc.text, linkd.text])`

Comment: Don't try to write large code blocks in comments, it's impossible to read.

Comment: If there's more to the problem, edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I updated the question with the last paragraph with comment :Update the below code

Comment: I don't know how I can thank you about all your efforts and your time!!
Kindly I need your contact if that applicable

Comment: Sorry, I don't give out contact information here. I answer the questions I choose.

Comment: thank you very much, and thank you for choosing my question,

Comment: Hello @Barmar, could you check this question it is related to my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737366/how-can-i-get-all-the-href-by-using-css-selector-and-find-elements?noredirect=1#comment98180027_55737366