# How can I get all the href by using css selector and find elements?

Tags: python, loops, selenium, for-loop

I'm using the below code and I want to get all Href in the elements not just first Href but when I use it I got only the first Href

```
communities = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2)>a')

sources = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.coin-link-row:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2)>a')
with open('example2.csv', 'a') as myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        for community, source in zip(communities, sources):
             writer.writerow([ community.get_attribute('href'), source.get_attribute('href')])
```

the html code which I wanted to gather the links from it, I want to gather all href by css selector, I need somthing like adding word all in the css selector path before letter a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="d-flex flex-column mx-3 mx-sm-5 mx-md-0">
    <div class="coin-link-row mb-md-0">
        <span class="coin-link-title mr-2">Market Cap</span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <span class="coin-tag mr-1 text-white bg-dark font-weight-bold">Rank #1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin-link-row mb-md-0">
        <span class="coin-link-title mr-2">Website</span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://www.bitcoin.org">
                <span class="">bitcoin.org</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin-link-row mb-md-0">
        <span class="coin-link-title mr-2">Explorers</span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks">
                <span class="">blockchair.com</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://blockchain.info/">
                <span class="">blockchain.info</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/">
                <span class="">live.blockcypher.com</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://bitcoinblockexplorers.com/">
                <span class="">bitcoinblockexplorers.com</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://btc.tokenview.com/">
                <span class="">btc.tokenview.com</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin-link-row mb-md-0">
        <span class="coin-link-title mr-2">Community</span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://reddit.com/r/Bitcoin">
                <i class="fab mr-sm-1 fa-reddit" />
                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Reddit</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://twitter.com/btc">
                <i class="fab mr-sm-1 fa-twitter" />
                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Twitter</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://www.facebook.com/134466763256650">
                <i class="fab mr-sm-1 fa-facebook" />
                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Facebook</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://bitcointalk.org/">
                <span class="">bitcointalk.org</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin-link-row mb-md-0">
        <span class="coin-link-title mr-2">Source Code</span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="coin-link-tag" href="https://github.com/bitcoin">
                <i class="fab mr-sm-1 fa-github" />
                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Github</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin-link-row mb-md-0">
        <span class="coin-link-title mr-2">Tags</span>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <span class="coin-tag mr-1">Cryptocurrency</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a sample of the html, without it it's a guessing game.

Comment: @TodorMinakov done I added the HTML code

Comment: There isn't a single element in the HTML that had the class "c-link-row" you reference in your question. Is what you added a "row" from a table you want to scrape?

Comment: @TodorMinakov the code is updated check now

Comment: OK, the source makes a difference; it's not just a table. `communities` returns 4 elements, `sources` - 1; the `zip()` function iterates over 2 lists simultaneously, up to the length of the shorter one. In this case - it iterates once. What are you trying to accomplish, the data in the 2 sets obviously does **not** map 1:1.

Comment: @Todor Minkakov so how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: The question is - what are you trying to accomplish, what should be written in the csv? Having 4 communities values and a single sources - what do you want to write there, row by row?

Comment: @Todor Minakov I want to gather all the links for example for the community in HTML code contains Twitter Facebook reddit I want to gather them all to be written in the CSV also the same thing for the explorer and so on